# Is SDIO used while the Raspberry Pi is in operation?

Tags: sd-card

Does the Raspberry PI use SDIO mode during its operation (at all)?

Im working on a ghosting capability device... Like clone on command without having to move any hardware.

Comment: It seems to me SDIO is purely a software issue, i.e., all SD card jacks are capable of SDIO transactions (but I could be wrong).  The current linux kernel does have a foundation for SDIO (see `[src]/drivers/mmc/core/`) and I think various device specific drivers...